# How to search through structure iteratively?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, loops, for-loop

## [PYTHON 3.7]

#### The premise of my query:

Taking backend code from a **LADDER** logic program and reconstructing data from the XML file.

I have a start STEP `S1`. The tree represents a sequence.
I want to iteratively cycle through the tree and create an ordered list of elements of that path between two steps (with `S1` being the first).

```
[graphical example]

           [S1]
            |          
          B3|_________ 
            |         |
           [T1]     [T7]
            |         |
            |       B4|
            |         |
           [S2]     [S3]
```

Ideal logic flow example:

```
[S1] --> [B3] --> [T1] --> [S2]
          |
          \--> [T7] --> [B4] --> [S3]
```

This results (ideally):

```
1: [ [S1], [B3], [T7], [B4], [S3] ]
2: [ [S1], [B3], [T1], [S2] ]
```

Some things to know:

- The end step can come directly from a transition or from a branch
- Each element has a unique identifier within its type
- Each element in the lists relate to the unique id and have information about the next connection

#### Data:

```
STEPS
con_steps = [[['StepRef', {'Number': '1'}], ['BranchRef', {'Number': '3', 'In': '0'}]], [['StepRef', {'Number': '3'}], ['BranchRef', {'Number': '11', 'In': '0'}]], [['StepRef', {'Number': '5'}], ['BranchRef', {'Number': '12', 'In': '0'}]], [['StepRef', {'Number': '4'}], ['BranchRef', {'Number': '13', 'In': '0'}]], [['StepRef', {'Number': '2'}], ['BranchRef', {'Number': '14', 'In': '0'}]]]

BRANCHES
con_brans = [[['BranchRef', {'Number': '3', 'Out': '0'}], ['TransitionRef', {'Number': '1'}]], [['BranchRef', {'Number': '3', 'Out': '1'}], ['TransitionRef', {'Number': '7'}]], [['BranchRef', {'Number': '4', 'Out': '0'}], ['StepRef', {'Number': '3'}]], [['BranchRef', {'Number': '11', 'Out': '0'}], ['TransitionRef', {'Number': '3'}]], [['BranchRef', {'Number': '11', 'Out': '1'}], ['TransitionRef', {'Number': '5'}]], [['BranchRef', {'Number': '12', 'Out': '0'}], ['TransitionRef', {'Number': '6'}]], [['BranchRef', {'Number': '12', 'Out': '1'}], ['TransitionRef', {'Number': '8'}]], [['BranchRef', {'Number': '13', 'Out': '0'}], ['TransitionRef', {'Number': '4'}]], [['BranchRef', {'Number': '13', 'Out': '1'}], ['TransitionRef', {'Number': '9'}]], [['BranchRef', {'Number': '14', 'Out': '0'}], ['TransitionRef', {'Number': '2'}]], [['BranchRef', {'Number': '14', 'Out': '1'}], ['TransitionRef', {'Number': '10'}]]]

TRANSITIONS
con_trans = [[['TransitionRef', {'Number': '2'}], ['BranchRef', {'Number': '4', 'In': '0'}]], [['TransitionRef', {'Number': '7'}], ['BranchRef', {'Number': '4', 'In': '1'}]], [['TransitionRef', {'Number': '3'}], ['StepRef', {'Number': '4'}]], [['TransitionRef', {'Number': '5'}], ['StepRef', {'Number': '5'}]], [['TransitionRef', {'Number': '1'}], ['StepRef', {'Number': '2'}]], [['TransitionRef', {'Number': '8'}], ['StepRef', {'Number': '2'}]], [['TransitionRef', {'Number': '6'}], ['StepRef', {'Number': '1'}]], [['TransitionRef', {'Number': '9'}], ['StepRef', {'Number': '2'}]], [['TransitionRef', {'Number': '4'}], ['StepRef', {'Number': '1'}]], [['TransitionRef', {'Number': '10'}], ['StepRef', {'Number': '1'}]]]
```

#### The aim:

Select a starting Step and Find all possible paths and create an ordered list of elements of that path.
Be able to iterate through all steps and end up with an array which has all the connections.

#### My attempt:

```
    S1 = []
    for i in con_steps:
        if i[0][1]['Number'] == '1':
            print(i)
            #save branch then cont.
            bran1 = i[1][1]['Number']

            tran1 = []
            for j in con_brans:
                if j[0][1]['Number'] == bran1:
                    print(j)
                    tran1.append(j[1][1]['Number'])


                    for k in tran1:
                        bran2 = []
                        for m in con_trans:
                            if m[0][1]['Number'] == k:
                                print(m)

                                if m[1][0] == 'StepRef':
                                    print('last step', m)
                                    S1.append(['1', m[1][1]['Number']])
                                else:
                                    bran2.append(j[1][1]['Number'])
                                    print('continue on', m)
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @Barmar How to do an iterative search through elements of a tree/structure which is linked and return all possible paths.

Comment: Wikipedia [Tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Comment: You need recursion, not just nested loops

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, very useful

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use recursion, you can obtain the same result using a deque object (from collections) which can act as a stack and avoid the recursion depth limit (also easier to debug):

```
def findNodes(nodeType,number):
    nodeList = {"StepRef":con_steps,"BranchRef":con_brans, "TransitionRef":con_trans}[nodeType]
    return [node for node in nodeList if node[0][1]["Number"] == number]

from collections import deque
def getPaths(start):
    q         = deque()
    result    = []
    firstNode = findNodes("StepRef",start)
    q.append(firstNode)
    seen      = set()
    while q:
        path       = q.popleft()
        nodeLink   = path[-1][1]
        linkType   = nodeLink[0]
        linkNumber = nodeLink[1]["Number"]            
        nextNodes  = findNodes(linkType,linkNumber)
        leafKey    = (path[-1][0][0],path[-1][0][1]["Number"])
        if leafKey in seen or not nextNodes:
            result.append(path)
            continue
        if leafKey[0] == "StepRef":
            seen.add(leafKey)
        for nextNode in nextNodes:
            q.append(path+[nextNode])
    return result
```

output:

```
paths = getPaths("1")
for path in paths:
    print( [f"{p[0][0][:1]}{p[0][1]['Number']}" for p in path])


['S1', 'B3', 'T1', 'S2', 'B14', 'T10', 'S1']
['S1', 'B3', 'T1', 'S2', 'B14', 'T2', 'B4', 'S3']
['S1', 'B3', 'T7', 'B4', 'S3', 'B11', 'T3', 'S4', 'B13', 'T4', 'S1']
['S1', 'B3', 'T7', 'B4', 'S3', 'B11', 'T3', 'S4', 'B13', 'T9', 'S2']
['S1', 'B3', 'T7', 'B4', 'S3', 'B11', 'T5', 'S5', 'B12', 'T6', 'S1']
['S1', 'B3', 'T7', 'B4', 'S3', 'B11', 'T5', 'S5', 'B12', 'T8', 'S2']
```

BTW, your data structure is very hard to manipulate.  You should consider using a common object class for all the nodes in the hierarchy so that traversal and manipulation doesn't require so much indexing.